iText pdf search for elements to create custom toc
I'm new to iText and need a solution to find specific objects form a pdf file.
The pdf file which I need to analyze was generated by the chrome browser and contains a table.
Now I want to read this pdf and create a new one with iText containing a toc.
After I found out that Chrome tagged the PDF, I think it should be possible to find individual rows of the table in the PDF and then insert them as a link into the table of content of the new pdf.
Any ideas how I can find out which table lines exists in which pdf page?
Thanks
Thomas
